# Is there a way to manage whole the form in the controller and then just print out a "form"variable in the view?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I don't want to use lot of php-stuff in my view when creating a form in codeigniter.

**The controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
                //Create login and register-forms
                $this->load->helper('form');

                $loginform_attributes = array('id' => 'login-form');                
                $data['loginform_attributes'] = $loginform_attributes;

                $this->load->view('home', $data);
    }
}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

**The view...**

```
echo form_open('login/register', $loginform_attributes);
```

**Is there a way to manage whole the form in the controller and then just print out `$form` in the view?** It doesn't seem to return anything when you try something like `$x = form_open('login/register', $loginform_attributes)`; in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using partial views and passing the content as a variable to the main view within the Controller, as follows:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        //Create login and register-forms
        $this->load->helper('form');

        $partial['loginform_attributes'] = array('id' => 'login-form');

        //Load the login form and assign the output to a variable
        $data['form'] = $this->load->view('partial/forms/login', $partial, TRUE);

        $this->load->view('home', $data);
    }
}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

From the [CI Doc](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html):

> `$this->load->view('file_name', $data, true/false)`
>
> The third optional parameter lets you change the behavior of the
>   function so that it returns data as a string rather than sending it to
>   your browser. This can be useful if you want to process the data in
>   some way. If you set the parameter to true (boolean) it will return
>   data.

Then in the `home` view, simply echo `$form` out.

```php
echo $form;
```